# How to give this slide show a sliding effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow

I am trying to give this a sliding effect instead of just fade in fade out when the image is changing, but I am not sure how to approach the issue.

My idea is to put all images on the same position and make one slide off the screen and make the next one slide in to the screen.

Is this the right approach, and how am I supposed to start it with code?

PS. I am trying to do this without any JS libraries

Answer (score 1):

With the current code, `fade-in` can be done pretty easily with CSS animations. For a starting point:

Try changing:

```
@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

To:

```
@keyframes fade {
  from {transform: translateX(100vw)} 
  to {transform: translateX(0)}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Would there be a way to make those slides connective? Your solution is great but the current slide immediately disappears when sliding.

Comment: Yeah, was leaving that up for you to examine how it works. The code in the `Tryit Editor` already catches the _sliding out_ element with JS and sets it's `display` property to `none`. This removes it from the DOM right away. You'll want to change this to make the element slide out, _then_ remove it from the DOM.

Comment: Does the sliding out effect also have to be in the fade animation, or will it be better to create another one called slideOut?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FJWTGZKK2LCI Here is what I've tried so far but the next element slides out before they appear again. What am I doing wrong?